# C# String to float with specific format

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to convert a string that is in the following format: `30,500` to convert to a float as `30.500` (in a json) So currently I have something like `float.Parse(string.Format("{0:00,000}", inp_km.Text), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)`, but when I save it in json, it saves as `30500.00`.

What am I doing wrong here?

How I just make it;

I make an object from the class `Results` like here;

```
team_results = new Results()
                        {
                            team_number = selected_team.team_number,
                            results = new Result[2] { new Result{ }, new Result { } }
                        };
```

Now when I add the new value to the json (example below) the input I get is `30,500`

```
[

  {
    "team_number": 101,
    "results": [
      {
        "given_start_time": "20:25",
        "connection_to_start":  "0:00",
        "start_kp": "20:26",
        "stop_kp": "0:0",
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "km": 0.000,
        "gtks": [ "25:00", "30:15", "0:00" ]
      },

      {
        "given_start_time": "21:56",
        "connection_to_start": "0:00",
        "start_kp": "21:57",
        "stop_kp": "0:0",
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "km": 0.000,
        "gtks": [ "25:00", "30:15" ]
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

But when it saves, it saves it as `30500.00`

Comment: A `float` object doesn't track any formatting, so when you write it out you'll need to specify the formatting or it will use a default format. Could you edit your question to show how you're writing the content to JSON?

Comment: Edited and added the Json format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to execute `Format` on a string which will just yield the same string as a result.

You want to *parse* the string and pass an `IFormatProvider` implementation to the `Parse` method that "understands" what `,` and `.` mean in the string representation of the number being parsed.

In the example below I used the culture `nl-NL` which has the same meaning as what you expect in your question (`.` for separating thousands and `,` for separating the fractional part of the number).

```
const string inputText = "30,500";
var result = float.Parse(inputText, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
Console.WriteLine("Parsed {0} to value {1}", inputText, result);
```

Comment: this may not work in case when nl-NL regional settings changed by user in regional settings.

Comment: @DmitryKolchev - There is not enough information to say that it will or won't work which is why I specified what is needed (2nd paragraph) and what I did in the 3rd paragraph to solve it (using a `CultureInfo`) but did not state that using `CultureInfo` was "the" solution. There is nothing here to suggest that the culture of the user is set on the local PC, this might be server side code (asp.net for example). The culture of the user might even be defined by the application (multi-tenant app) or in the user profile or by a browser context.

Comment: exactly, because of this parsing should rely on expected data input not infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom NumberFormatInfo

```
var nf = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
nf.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
nf.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
```

and use it to Parse numeric value

```
Console.WriteLine(float.Parse("30,5000", nf));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , I have a solution but it would not be the best but it will work .
as you are working on a string you can use this function

```
string converter(string s)
{
s = s.Replace('.',',');
return s;
}
```

also check this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx